# How do I convert my existing zip files to 7z with 7-zip comand line?

Tags: conversion, zip, 7-zip, packer

I'd like to convert a couple thousand zip files to 7z, with maximum compression and multithreading enabled.

Also in another place. Like c:\temp\file.zip to f:\converted\file.7z

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arepack` (included in [`atool` command suite](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/)) to convert between archive formats. Combined with a little bash, it makes easy to convert a bunch of ZIP files to 7z:

```
for f in *.zip; do arepack $f $f.7z; done
rm *.zip
```

Comment: You can use `--each`/`-e` to let `arepack` do the iteration for you: `arepack --each --format=7z *.zip`

Comment: @JoelPurra the `arepack`-only solution is best! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, http://www.peazip.org/ does the job just fine!

Edit: But hell, it takes way too long....

Comment: And it also can't handle *some* zips that contain filenames in "bad" encodings like cp1251 or koi8r or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script in Python - https://raw.github.com/pashinin/scripts/master/zip27z.py
You can run it with:

```
./zip27z.py your_archive.zip
```

and it will create your_archive.7z near it.

Or you can install it on your system with `make install` (if you see the repo)

And just call:

```
zip27z your_archive.zip
```

It needs `unzip` and `7za` programs.

You can modify it as you wish for your needs (and send me a pull request)